# Where do I find the applications menu editor?

Tags: unity, gnome, wine, menu

In a Ubuntu forum, I was researching on how to open wine programs. I found some instructions that may be useful. I can successfully download the programs, but I don't know how to open them. Here the instructions.

1. Open Applications Menu Editor
   **Applications** --> **System Tools** -> **Application Menu Editor**
2. Click The New Menu Button. Fill Out Wine Apps (or whatever you want)
   for the name. and hit enter. You can Add an Icon if you wish, i
   prefer to keep mine default for now..
3. Click On The New Menu Item You Just Created. Now Click The Button
   That Says New Entry.
   Fill Out the Form the way you like. as for the command. youll want
   to enter: `wine /home/{user}/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/{path to
   your program.exe}`
4. Choose an Icon If You Wish, again i didnt due to preference. And
   lastly you want to click the 'run in terminal' button.
5. Close The Menu Editor And Voila! You Now have a quick and easy way
   to launch your favorite windoz programs ^_^. I think this is a good
   howto.. considering if its one youll use alot... doing this will
   save you quite some time in the end..

I keep getting stuck on the first step. I can't seem to find the Applications Menu Editor. I know that this is probably a simple question, but could someone tell me where to find that? Again, thank you in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install `alacarte` :

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

It's an application menu editor.

Comment: thanks! help me find the Wunderlist that auto-installed without I asking, it is at 'Other'; now I only have to discover how it got there..

Comment: `alacarte` is broken in Ubuntu 22.04, using `menulibre` works for me.

Answer (score 5):

As addition to the previous answer, you may also want to try `menulibre`.

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Comment: This worked for me, `alacarte` is broken in Ubuntu 22.04.